# how to stay in modal window even after submit form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

There is a form in modal window. I am calliing ajax to load content on the same modal window. But the problem is it reverts to the main page after submitting form. How do I stay on the same modal window even after submitting form? Below code is in model window...

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="editgroupscript" class="btn green" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

modal window code:

```
<!-- ### Modal ###   -->
     <div id="edit_script" class="modal hide">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"></button>
           <h3>Edit Script</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
<!-- some content -->
```

Is there anything we need to put in action ?

Comment: can you post some code?  i'm guessing you're submitting the form to a server side script.  you'll want to use the jQuery .submit() method http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/fivelive/mayo/rss.xml

Comment: Look into [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It's really worth taking the time to read.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options -

Option 1: Submit the form via Javascript

```
<form action="http://www.yoursite.com/form.xxx" method="post">
<input type="button" name="editgroupscript" class="btn green" value="Submit" onclick="formSubmitFunction()" />
</form>

Javascript:
function ajax() {
  var obj;
  if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    try {
  obj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e) {
  obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
  }
  else {
    obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return (obj);
}

function formSubmitFunction() {
  // Creating the POST body
  var myForm = document.forms["myForm"];
  var value1 = myForm["value1"].value;
  var value2 = myForm["value2"].value;
  var parameters = "value1="+value1+"&value2="+value2;

  // Sending a POST via AJAX
  var ajax = ajax();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if((ajax.readyState == 4) && (ajax.status == 200)) {
      // Action on successful response
    }
  };
  ajax.send("POST", "yourURL", true);
  ajax.send(parameters);
}
```

Option 2: Target the form to an iframe

```
<form action="http://www.yoursite.com/form.xxx" method="post" target="iframe">
<input type="submit" name="editgroupscript" class="btn green" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<iframe src="about:blank" style="display:none" id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>

Javascript:
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
iframe.onload = function () { formSubmitResponse(iframe); };
function formSubmitResponse(iframe) {
  var idocument = (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document);
  if(idocument) {
    var responseFromBackend = idocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Here's what happens when you use an iframe:
1. Click the submit button.
2. Form parameters get submitted to the back-end script.
3. Page doesn't refresh.
4. Output from the back-end script is sent to the iframe.
5. This method mimicks AJAX!

Comment: Can you elaborate please.. how can I submit the form through javascript?

Comment: I want to pass that form variable into javascript and process another php form to get data in the same page. iframe works for me.. but will it pass form variable to javascript?

<iframe src="about:blank" style="display:none" id="iframe" onsubmit="ChooseGroupScript(this)"></iframe>

Comment: By Javascript I mean you can submit the form via AJAX. I'll edit the answer by adding an example.

Comment: In Javascript you can search for variables like this - document.forms["formName"]["variableName"].value. Once you collect the variables you can pass them to the back-end by making an AJAX call. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I used iframe as you said in your answer. I can stay on the same modal window by submitting form. but I can't pass form parameters by means of onsubmit event.

Comment: how to bind form parameters to the iframe?

Comment: The form will directly submit to the back-end script, you don't need an onsubmit event on the iframe. The iframe will only collect the output from the back-end script.

Comment: then how will I pass form parameters to the backend?

Comment: You don't need to. That happens just like a regular form. All you need to do is to collect the output from the backend script from the iframe. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: And you need to add the url that you are submitting the form to, in ACTION

Comment: Both the options elaborated in my answer will help you stay in the modal window.

Comment: I applied first option.. I can't stay in same window. so, I can't analyze whether I ma getting form parameters or not.

Comment: when applying the 1st option, did you change the type from "submit" to "button"?

Comment: yes.. I changed that one. when I remove document.getElementById("myform").submit();
then I can stay on the same page but I am not getting form parameters (it's obvious) when I add that line (it's necessary) then that modal window disappears.

Comment: Finally, I am not getting the form parameters.. form remains as it is when submitting it..

Comment: don't do this - "document.getElementById("myform").submit();". you'll have to submit the form via AJAX. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. I solved my problem through jquery.